How to get my website working with google cloud?
So, I bought a Domain in Hostgator, changed the NameServers to ns1.siteground.net & ns2.siteground.net (because the content of my website is there). I checked all the DNS and they are pointing out to 35.215.123.83 (that is google cloud), also, the DNS Propagation is already OK. But for some reason the website still shows the error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, can anyone solve this?
the website is shalemmistica.com
I Waited 72h to te propagation but it's still not working.

Seems to be working to me, I'm seeing a Wordpress site at that domain

What :( I get the error everytime I try to acces the site, maybe its the internet cache or smth?
